# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating - Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Im not sure where this error is coming from, it occurs when I hit back on the navigation controller and go to the previous screen, I am guessing it has to do with something in `viewWillAppear` but this is all that in it

```
self.view.backgroundColor = mainColor;
self.topView.backgroundColor = mainColor;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:offSetColor];
profileBtn.tintColor = tempColor;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18], NSFontAttributeName,tempColor,
                                                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

[imageView setImage:self.homeImage];

self.title = self.titleReal;
```

Not sure how any of that could cause a problem the second time, when I go back to this screen when it works fine the first time?

Thanks for the help

Comment: mhm.. I suspect that topView is a reference to the ViewController you are popping? else I don't see anything here

Comment: @Daij-Djan no sorry I didn't explain that top view is just a header above the UITableView when the image view is, it is on the first view controller that loads, then I push to the next one and then when I come back to the first view controller I get the warning

Comment: ok . then. in the 2nd view controller, override `-(UIView*)view { return [super view]; }` - break on that line to find the one calling the view

Comment: @Daij-Djan no where on the 2nd view controller is there `-(UIView*)view { return [super view]; }`

Comment: @Daij-Djan the waring occurs on the first view controller after going back, I put a break point in `viewDidAppear` and the warning occurs after `viewDidAppear` has finished

Comment: no there isn't. you need to override it. It isn't there an it isn't needed either. :D -- check the first VC's viewDidDisappear method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95285/discussion-between-spenf10-and-daij-djan).